# How do I create a simple route in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am writing a short url service in MVC3, partly as a learning tool.

When I load the url http://mysite/abc I want to redirect to an action in my controller with the following signature:

```
public ActionResult RedirectToLink(string shortLink)
```

How would I create a route in order to run this code?  I have tried the following:

```
routes.MapRoute("Link", "{shortLink}", new { controller = "LinkController", action = "RedirectToLink" });
```

Alternatively, if someone can point me towards a decent primer for MVC3 that actually covers the basics rather than what's changed since the last version and would cover this scenario, I'd be much obliged.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the route your want :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "ShortLink", // Route name
    "{shortLink}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Link", // Parameter defaults
    action = "RedirectToLink",
    shortLink= UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404 when I try that, I have also tried setting the controller = "Link" as I noticed the default one omits the Controller part of the class.

Comment: Actually it does work, once I had moved the MapRoute above the "Default" one, I assume this is a special name that causes others to be ignored

Comment: Thanks muchly, I'm slowly wading my way through this :)

Comment: Regarding "Default" I *think* the routes are handled by first matching route.